# How to use OpenMP to solve π value and accurate to 100 digits ？

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <omp.h> 
#define MAX_N 100000000
#define NUM_THREADS 4
int main()
{
    int i;
    double x, pi, step, sum = 0.0, start, stop;
    step = 1.0 / (double)MAX_N;
    omp_set_num_threads(NUM_THREADS);
    start = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum) private(x) 
    for (i = 1; i <= MAX_N; i++) {
        x = (i - 0.5) * step;
        sum = sum + 4.0 / (1.0 + x * x);
    }

    pi = step * sum;
    stop = omp_get_wtime();

    printf("pi=%.100lf\n", pi);
    printf("time = %lf\n", stop - start);
    return 0;
}
```

My result is
pi=3.1415926535898210936181840224890038371086120605468750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I think it may be because the accuracy exceeds “lf”.

So how can I solve this problem ?

Should I change to another algorithm? Or other methods ？

Thanks

Comment: Not with `double`s, that's for sure. You'd need an arbitrary precision decimal library.

Comment: Such as GMP?I don’t know if I am allowed to use.Thank you

Comment: Then you might want to look at the prior art for pi-computing and figure out if there's an algorithm you can implement yourself.

Comment: Yes, I found an algorithm called "BBP", but I need time to implement it in the program